# Antd Modal not working

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, antd

I'm making a react app using antd, I'm trying to add modal but it doesn't work, every time I click the trigger button I got errors saying "*Uncaught Error: Element ref was specified as a string (header) but no owner was set. You may have multiple copies of React loaded.*". Im following this syntax from https://ant.design/components/modal/

I found related problem https://github.com/jrm2k6/react-markdown-editor/issues/55

and according to react

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs

they dont recommend using **ref attribute**, instead use a callback pattern.

I dont know what to do..

Any help, thanks.

Comment: are you using `ref` somewhere?

Comment: Check t,hat you are using compatible versions. React 15 goes with AntD 2.x, React 16 with AntD 3.x

Comment: @azium This is the syntax their using .. <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>Open</Button>

Comment: @JesperWe im using react 16 and antD 3.x

Comment: @MarkGerrylMirandilla were you able to find a solution? I'm currently experiencing this same issue with react 16.2.0 and antd 3.3.0

Comment: no sir, im still looking for the solution